# Relations between abstract models in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Is there any way to create base abstract models and implement some kind of fake relations between them instead of re-defining the same relations in each inherited real models?
I've made this models.py for testing purposes:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models


class BaseSource(models.Model):
    source_field = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    source_field1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    pointers = GenericRelation('BasePointer')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def print_pointers(self):
        for pointer in self.pointers.all():
            print(pointer.pointer_field)


class BasePointer(models.Model):
    pointer_field = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    source_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    source = GenericForeignKey(source_type, source_id)


class Source(BaseSource):
    pass


class Source2(BaseSource):
    pass


class Pointer(BasePointer):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, related_name='pointers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Pointer2(BasePointer):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source2, related_name='pointers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The reason is to provide a way to switch current models (Source+Pointer and Source2+Pointer2) depending on user's choice, models will be mostly the same with minor differences, so I don't want to make them completely different classes.
Most fields and logic are described in base abstract models, and real models are using different tables in database, views will be determining current models set and provide specific context variables, if needed.
The problem is relations between those models: example method - print_pointers, which uses non-declared field self.pointers. I've tried declaring GenericRelation('BasePointer') as fake relation, but can't migrate it because of error:
`test_models.Source2.pointers: (fields.E307) The field test_models.Source2.pointers was declared with a lazy reference to 'test_models.basepointer', but app 'test_models' doesn't provide model 'base pointer'.`

The best way I've found for now is declaring all relations in real models and ignoring IDE warnings of unresolved attribute references (pointers in example). Is there any better solution?
Thanks in advance, sorry for my english))

Comment: Why not just have a One to One with a common model? i.e. there are two models `Source` and `Pointer` (not abstract) that are related to each other. Next have a one to one relationship between `Source` and `Source1` similarly for `Source2` and pointers.

Comment: These are 2 large amounts of data which can somehow conflict between each other, so it looks better to use completely different tables with mostly the same structure and logic. The main difference is urls.py, like `/data/123` - to view default data and `/additional/123` - to the same view but with some flag pointing that data will be retrieved from additional tables and displayed in the same template etc.